# How to use multiple, comma separated route params in Vue router

Tags: url, frontend, vuejs3, vue-router4

I want to set up a route that can take optional params `x` and `y`, both of which can be multiple.
The issue I am facing is that vue router only seem to be able to extract actual route segments (delimited by `/`) into single items in the resulting `route.params` array:

```js
// For a single route parameter

path: '/route/:x*'

// Given a URL like '/route/foo/bar' the route.params will be:

['foo', 'bar']

// However, a given route like '/route/foo,bar will result in:

['foo, bar']
```

Similarly, navigating to this route via `router.push({ name: 'route', params: { collection: ['foo', 'bar'] }})`, the resulting route will still be slash rather than comma separated.

Ultimately, best case scenario would be a pattern in the lines of:

`path: '/route/:x*/:y*'`

Where both `x` and `y` are optional and can be disambiguated  via prefixes, e.g.:

```
path: 'route/:x(foo_.*)?/:y(bar_.*)?'
```

In turn,
`/route`,
`/route/foo_123`,
`/route/foo_123,foo_456`,
`/route/foo_123/bar_123` and
`/route/bar_123`

will all route to the same location and the router will provide the params in this fashion:

```js
params: {
   x: ['foo_123', ...],
   y: ['bar_456', ...]
}
```

I tried a couple of approaches using custom regex as described in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html). Unfortunately though, it does not provide any example of multiple optional route params.

Comment: The key point is to separate the params with a comma instead of a slash as one typically does, yes?

Comment: After playing around with it for some time I don’t think it’s possible - maybe even because it’s not standard practice. I went with query params instead…